# How do I only call the onClick() function to a single React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

There is a function called `Question` that takes a list of objects (`questionList`) and changes each object into a React component that shows a question and when clicked should reveal the answer in a FAQ style. There is another function called `Answer` which shows the answer when a `Question` container is clicked. However, instead of showing the answer of just the container which was clicked, it shows every answer of all the questions - as if rendered all the questions again with their answers. When a container is clicked again, all `Answer` containers are hidden.

How do I only show the answer of the specific `Question` container?

**Example:**

1. How does this work?
2. What do you do?

*click on 2*

1. How does this work?

   - *Answer to 1*
2. What do you do?

   - *Answer to 2*

Instead of:

1. How does this work?
2. What do you do?

   - *Answer to 2*

```
function Question(props) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const onClick = () => {
        if (show) {
            setShow(false);
        } else {
            setShow(true);
        }
    };

    const questionList = props.questionList;
    const questions = questionList.map(question => (
        <div onClick={onClick} className="container">
            <div className="line"></div>
            <div className="question-container">
                <h3 className="question">{question.question}</h3>
                <div className="drop-icon">
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

            {show ? <Answer question={question} /> : null}
        </div>
    ));
    return <section>{questions}</section>;
}

function Answer(props) {
    const question = props.question;
    const answer = (
        <div className="answer">
            <p>{question.answer}</p>
        </div>
    );
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the state `show` is just one value while each item should probably have their own `show` for the desired result.

Try make `show` an object (or array) that stores a `boolean` value for each item in the list:

```
function Question({ questionList }) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState({});
  const onClick = (index) =>
    setShow((prev) => ({ ...prev, [index]: !Boolean(prev[index]) }));

  const questions = questionList.map((question, index) => (
    <div key={index} onClick={() => onClick(index)} className="container">
      <div className="line"></div>
      <div className="question-container">
        <h3 className="question">{question.question}</h3>
        <div className="drop-icon">
          <i className="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      {show[index] ? <Answer question={question} /> : null}
    </div>
  ));
  return <section>{questions}</section>;
}
```

Or consider to make each question a component `QuestionItem` (like `Answer` in the example) that has its own `show` state:

```
const QuestionItem = ({ question }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const onClick = () => setShow((prev) => !prev);
  return (
    <div onClick={onClick} className="container">
      <div className="line"></div>
      <div className="question-container">
        <h3 className="question">{question.question}</h3>
        <div className="drop-icon">
          <i className="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      {show ? <Answer question={question} /> : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And iterate the component `QuestionItem` in `Question`:

```
function Question({ questionList }) {
  const questions = questionList.map((question, index) => (
    <QuestionItem key={index} question={question} />
  ));
  return <section>{questions}</section>;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this line works: `setShow((prev) => ({ ...prev, [index]: !Boolean(prev[index]) }));`? I don't understand the `...prev, [index]` part especially.

Comment: @tices Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax and open a new question if you have a specific thing in mind.

Comment: @tices This line pass a setter function for `setShow`, which gets `prev`  with the previous value as an argument. The return `{...prev, [index]: !Boolean(prev[index])}` updates the object with existing values, only changing the related key from `true` to `false`, or from `undefined` or `false` to `true`.  Check [updating-objects-in-state](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state) from React docs for a complete guide of this topic.

Comment: Why did you have to use to spread operator with `...prev`? Why was it included in the first place?

Comment: It does make a lot more sense now though thanks to the documentation.

Comment: @tices The `return` is a new object (to avoid mutating the state), and `{...prev}` makes a copy of `prev` before updating the key `[index]`, so in result you get a new object like the previous one, just had this key updated.